# Find path with maximum cost difference of edges in directed graph in linear-time

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Having a directed graph `G` with edges having positive weights, we define the cost of a path the difference between the edge with minimum weight and maximum weight. The goal is to find a path with maximum cost among other paths. We don't need to return the path itself just the maximum cost.

If `x` is the number of vertices and `y` is the number of edges then  `x < 10^5` and `y < min(x^2,10^5)`. The time limit is 1 second.

Based on the bounds I think this problem has to be solved in `O(x+y)` time.

So based on the problems properties ans some studying of other algorithms  I thought that on possible answer may contain multiple `DFS`'s (like the SCC problem). I also find a [similar problem](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/graph-max-min-node-capacity) with Dijkstra's algorithm that can be modified for this problem but I'm not very sure that the complexity would be OK. Also there are some other questions similar to mine however the answers were of `O(m^2)` or higher which were not very efficient.

Other than what was mentioned above I have no idea to solve the problem and some insight would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Do a simple dfs while maintaining the minimum and maximum edge weights for each node seen until now. Maintain a running difference to get the maximal cost.

Comment: Usually when there is `10^5` of something and a time limit of 1 second, the expected time complexity is `O(10^5 * log(10^5))`. I bet Dijkstra's algorithm will be suitable here by time complexity `O(m * log(n))`. Where `m` here is count of edges, and `n` is a count of vertexes.

Comment: @SerialLazer this algorithm is wrong, because one vertex can be updated a few times. You may not be lucky and you will not follow the right path to the final vertex. And if you do dfs by going to already visited vertices, then you will actually handle all the paths, but the time complexity will be exactly greater than `O(m * log(n))`

Comment: @Iaroslav Sviridov the Dijkstra algorithm needs a start node and end node to work bu‍t here we should check all paths. I think this would multiple your time complexity by ‍‍‍ `O(n^2)` and this is a problem

Comment: @FrastoFresto Dijkstra calculate distance not only for 1 end node, but for all nodes except start node. We can run Dijkstra for all starting nodes, therefore, the final time complexity will be increased by `n` times, not `n^2`.

Comment: @Iaroslav Sviridov doesn't that make the complexity `n*O(m * log(n))`?

Comment: @FrastoFresto maybe there is a more optimal algorithm,  I need to think about it. `O(n * m * log(n))` is more than 1 second

Comment: @FrastoFresto is it true, that graph can contain a cycle like A -> B -> ... -> A?

Comment: @Iaroslav Sviridov yes it can contain cycles

Comment: @FrastoFresto Okay, I know how to do it in `O(|V| + |E|)` time complexity with advanced algorithms, and it quite hard to implement. Have you heard anything about strongly connected components and topological sort?

Comment: @Iaroslav Sviridov yes I heard about both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
Due to the fact that our graph can have cycles, this complicates things for us. Let's build a new graph in which we "compress" all the [components of a strong connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) into a single vertex, so new graph will be acyclic. During this process let's memorize maximum(`maximumWeight[v]`) and minimum(`minimumWeigh[v]`) weights of the edges for each strongly connected components.
We spent `O(|V| + |E|)` time for it, where `|V|` is count of vertexes and `|E|` is count if edges.

After that let's make a [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of given graph in `O(|V|+|E|)` time complexity. Then let's calculate simple DP.

`dpMax[v]` - the maximum weight of the edge to which there is a path from this vertex.
`dpMin[v]` - the minimum weight of the edge to which there is a path from this vertex.

Default value:
If vertex `v` is strongly connected component, then maximum and minimum weights already calculates in `maximumWeight[v]` and `minimumWeigh[v]`, so `dpMax[v] = maximumWeight[v]` and `dpMin[v] = minimumWeight[v]`.
Otherwise `maximumWeight[v] = -Infinity` and `minimumWeigh[v] = Infinity`.

In topological order let's improve our DP for each vertex:

```
int answer = -Infinity;
for(auto v : vertexesInTopologicalOrder) {
    int newMinDp = dpMin[v], newMaxDp = dpMax[v];
    for(auto e : v.outgoingEdges) {
        int l = dpMin[v];
        int r = dpMax[v];
        l = min(l, e.weight);
        r = max(r, e.weight);
        l = min(l, dpMin[e.target]);
        r = max(r, dpMax[e.target]);
        answer = max(answer, e.weight - l);
        answer = max(answer, r - e.weight);
        newMinDp = min(newMinDp, l);
        newMaxDp = max(newMaxDp, r);
    }
    dpMin[v] = newMinDp;
    dpMax[v] = newMaxDp;
}
```

Since we calculating DP in topological order, the DP at achievable vertexes have already been calculated.

For a better understanding, let's look at an example.

Let's say we have such an initial graph.
[image: Let's say we have such an initial graph.]

After compression, the graph will look something like this.
[image: After compression, the graph will look something like this.]

After topological sorting, we get this order of vertices. (Green numbers)
[image: After topological sorting, we get this order of vertices. (Green numbers)]

Sequentially calculate all DP values, along with updating the answer.
[image: Sequentially calculate all DP values, along with updating the answer.]

Final answer 6 will be achieved during calculating top vertex DP.

I hope it turned out to be quite detailed and clear. Final time complexity is `O(|V|+|E|)`.

Comment: @FrastoFresto Yes, you are right, I will fix it a little bit later. Thank you.

Comment: @FrastoFresto I fixed, check it please on your graph.